# Searching for a value within a string or range

Tags: vb.net

I would like to do a ZIPCode look up and based on a value specified have it return a value from a look up string.  Not sure what the most effecient method is.

```
Lookup Table
Location To Return        Value to Lookup
New York, NY              140 - 150, 152 - 158
Los Angelas, CA           900 - 910, 930 - 990
```

I would prefer to have the tables stored in a text file so updating the lookup values can be done without have to recompile with hard data.

PS: Using VS2013

Comment: ok, they are in a text file on disk, but how is the data stored in teh app?  is it already stored somewhere or is that what you are asking?

Comment: That is what I am asking.  What would be the best method of formatting the text file to facilitate the look up.  Currently, I'm taking the entered ZIP from a Textbox to a List Box but between posting into the listbox I would like the lookup to occur and return the proper value.

Comment: did you know the USPS has a ZipCode API?  you are basically recreating that wheel without the auto update aspect as it changes.  Why a text file instead of a DB?  SQL would make this simple.

Comment: I am well aware of the API's offered by the USPS (have actually worked with their look up tools) and used this as an example.   I am actually writing a shipping utility that takes an input value and translate to a return value based on a range to look thru.

I would prefer a text file over a DB/SQL table as it has to be freestanding and easily updated.

Comment: the problem is that your sample data is misleading.  those cities have multiple 3 digit Zips, but the USPS Zip csv lists 40 valid locations for `270`. that makes it difficult to both store the data sensibly and  return a single location.  An Access DB updated from that CSV would be both freestanding and easily updated.  Is your app for a severely limited subset of cities/zips?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a utility for entering the data in whatever format is easiest to enter. If there is an existing data file, read it in and parse the data into the entry format. Parse the entered data to make a text file of lines `"123","abcdef, xy"` where each entry is in double-quotes, one entry per three-digit code.

Then you can use a [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) with the appropriate settings to read the data into an array of strings where the index is the number. It will only be an array of 1,000 strings, so memory is likely not a consideration.

This method makes it easy to enter data, easy for your program to load the data, and gives almost instant look-ups. The text file can still be edited by hand if absolutely necessary.